# Rectangle - a mathematical problem

Tags: math, language-agnostic

I have found something NOT funny with rectangles:

Lets say, given are values of left, top, right and bottom coordinates and all those coordinates are intended to be inclusive.

So, calculating the width goes like:

```
width = right - left + 1
```

So far, so logical. But!

A width of zero (which makes sense, sometimes) would have to be stored as:

```
right = left - 1
```

which makes problems, when it comes to the following operations:

- Sorting the rectangle coordinates (to make it go left to right, top to bottom)
- Looping

Ok, of course those things can be handled with extra code for the special case of `Width == 0`, but, seriously, is there no better solution, no standard pattern or best practice to handle this?

Edit:

For the time being I have abandoned the "sorting" of the coordinates in my code and replaced it with an assertion stating that the rectangle must be left -> right, up -> down, but seriously...

Comment: This is why rectangles are usually handled as two sides and both dimensions.

Comment: What? width=right-left, not right-left+1. A rectangle spanning from left=2.5 to right=3.8 has width 1.3, not 2.3. What sort of coordinates are you working with?

Comment: I use (don't laugh, please, we're talking about a console application here!) shorts. :-)

Comment: @shreevatsar: pixels.. so from pixel 1 to 2 (inclusive) the width is 2.

Comment: What's the problem with looping? In your described system, you loop over the columns of a rectangle with `for (x = left; x <= right; ++x)`. If `right == left-1`, the loop body is executed 0 times. It's true though that you can't easily sort all the vertical edges of a collection of rectangles using their `left` and `right` values.

Comment: @yi_H: Thanks, that sort of makes sense, but pixels are not points (they have area) so it's clearly a bad idea to use them as "coordinates". As Paul R's answer (or Greg Hewgill's answer) shows, it's better to treat pixels as the areas between actual coordinates. With any *true* coordinate system, you would have width=right-left, without any "+1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address this problem, most graphics libraries will draw rectangles from the left coordinate up to but *not including* the right coordinate. So if left=10 and right=20, then the ten pixels 10 through 19 will be drawn.

You can think of this as the pixel coordinate referring not to the lit-up portion, but the grid lines *between* pixels.

```
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
^   ^   ^   ^
0   1   2   3
```

Answer (score 2):

It's important to distinguish between *coordinates* and *pixels*. You can think of the coordinate system as being an invisible grid which runs *between* pixels. Thinking of coordinates this way if you define a rect as { 0, 3, 0, 5 }, then you get 3 pixels by 5 pixels as expected.

```
   |  |  |  |  |  |
0 -x--+--+--+--+--x-
   |  |  |  |  |  | 
1 -+--+--+--+--+--+-
   |  |  |  |  |  | <- pixels are rectangular areas between coordinate grid
2 -+--+--+--+--+--+-
   |  |  |  |  |  | 
3 -x--+--+--+--+--x-
   |  |  |  |  |  | 
   0  1  2  3  4  5
```

Answer (score 2):

If the edges (left, right, top, bottom) are inclusive then, by definition, the width (and height) of the rectangle cannot be 0. By "including" the side (which is a pixel), you're saying that it has to be at least 1 pixel wide.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can find a workaround for this, but what really is the problem here is going **out of scope**.

Your scope is a rectangle, and even if a width of zero would come in handy : there is **no such thing as a rectangle with width zero.**

Normally all functions have **contracts** and a predcondition of a functions that says `docalculation(par_rectangle)` is that par_rectangle in fact *is* a rectangle.

If you need a retangle-*like* object wich can be width zero, you first need to define it waterproof, and never just assert that rules for rectangles will apply on your definiton.

Comment: Actually true, but I need the case of rendering an item which is in a widget too small to display everything.

Comment: Who says there is no such thing as a rectangle with width 0? A rectangle is a set of points, and rectangle with width 0 corresponds to the empty set. It all depends on your definition of "rectangle"; certainly the usual mathematical definitions don't preclude width 0.

Comment: A bunch of math-people indeed.  A rectangle needs straigth angles, no such thing i possible with width 0.  Of course the screen is always a simplification of real math, but coordinates [0,0] [0,1] and [1,0] are forming a straight angle for example  (or general [x,y], [x,y+1], [x+1,y] always minimum width 1 thus)

Comment: And saying a rectangle is a set of points, is a way of implementing it, not a definition (all screen elements are a bunch of points or at least a translation from vectors to a bunch of points), and when supporting the empty set, you are actually going beyond rectangle logics wich lead to this kind of problems in the first place.

Comment: Fine, a definition in terms of right angles (ITYM right angles, not "straight angles") is appropriate for elementary geometry. An alternative definition of rectangles is as the Cartesian product of two intervals, and in that case one can allow empty intervals. The point is that it is a matter of definitions. (In fact, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle also talks of "crossed rectangles" which come from directed intervals and do not have right angles.) Also, you can *define* points A, B, C as forming a right angle if the dot product (A-B).(B-C)=0, and when A=B this is trivially satisfied.

Comment: Still of no importance, a rectangle is always 2-dimensional, a rectangle without width isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Saying that

> all those coordinates are intended to be inclusive

means that there actually are *two distinct rectangles*, one within another. That's where you get caught: when you write

```
width = right - left + 1
```

it really means:

```
inner_width = outer_right - outer_left + thickness
```

where `thickness` is the distance between corresponding sides of inner and outer rectangles.

So, to deal with the problem in abstract mathematical sense, you have to consider two rectangles instead of one.

Comment: This is the best answer, but since I'm implementing a TUI framework, I can't really go for this (mathematically and logically absolutely perfect) solution. However, thank you very, very much! :-)

Comment: @StormianRootSolver: yeah, I've been to such situation too :) You're always welcome.